# Whats wrong about this JS file on Material Admin , Hide side bar is not work

Tags: jquery, css, sidebar

I am using template material admin and I have some problem in the sidebar js - it does not work .

```html
</div>
<div class="mdc-list-group hide">
  <nav class="mdc-list mdc-drawer-menu "> // this sidebar is here
    <div class="mdc-list-item mdc-drawer-item">
      <a class="mdc-drawer-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dinas">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__start-detail mdc-drawer-item-icon" aria-hidden="true">desktop_mac</i>
```

and this file JS is here

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  $(function() {
    var body = $('body');
    var contentWrapper = $('.content-wrapper');
    var scroller = $('.container-scroller');
    var footer = $('.footer');
    var sidebar = $('.mdc-drawer-menu');

    // Menu Toggle Function
    var drawerEl = document.querySelector('.mdc-persistent-drawer');
    var MDCPersistentDrawer = mdc.drawer.MDCPersistentDrawer;
    var drawer = new MDCPersistentDrawer(drawerEl);
    document.querySelector('.menu-toggler').addEventListener('click', function() {
      drawer.open = !drawer.open;
    });

    //Add active class to nav-link based on url dynamically
    //Active class can be hard coded directly in html file also as required
    var current = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0].replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
    $('.mdc-drawer-item .mdc-drawer-link', sidebar).each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if (current === "") {
        //for root url
        if ($this.attr('href').indexOf("index.html") !== -1) {
          $(this).addClass('active');
          if ($(this).parents('.mdc-expansion-panel').length) {
            $(this).closest('.mdc-expansion-panel').addClass('expanded');
          }
        }
      } else {
        //for other url
        if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
          $(this).addClass('active');
          if ($(this).parents('.mdc-expansion-panel').length) {
            $(this).closest('.mdc-expansion-panel').addClass('expanded');
          }
        }
      }
    })

    $(".mdc-toolbar__menu-icon").on("click", function() {
      $(".body-wrapper .page-wrapper .content-wrapper").toggleClass("drawer-minimized");
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

#### Error message:

> jquery.min.js:2 **jQuery.Deferred exception: mdc is not defined ReferenceError: mdc is not defined**
>       at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost/skripsi/assets/template/assets/js/misc.js:12:31)
>       at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
>       at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677)
>   undefined w.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2 c @
>   jquery.min.js:2 setTimeout (async) (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2 u @
>   jquery.min.js:2 fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2 fire @ jquery.min.js:2 u @
>   jquery.min.js:2 fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2 ready @ jquery.min.js:2
>   _ @ jquery.min.js:2 jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: mdc is not defined ReferenceError: mdc is not defined
>       at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost/skripsi/assets/template/assets/js/material.js:16:5)
>       at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
>       at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677)
>   undefined

I don't know about this `mdc` , it's js for this template but it's not included in template . I add Jquery from CDN google but it did not help. 
Please help me finding solution

Comment: `mdc` appears to be a reference to the **M**aterial **D**esign **C**omponents library - did that reference on line 12 of your JS snippet come from a template or did you add that?

Comment: how i can get Material Design Components library sir , this template using this library but not included that . emmm u mean i need using Material Design Components library JS ? how i can get that

Comment: You can find a getting started guide on their GitHub repo, which includes [this section](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#quick-start-cdn) on including their javascript files

Comment: line 12 is  var MDCPersistentDrawer = mdc.drawer.MDCPersistentDrawer;

Comment: this section need me to install npm .

Comment: That’s to install locally. You just need the section I linked, **Quick Start (CDN)**

Comment: ok i use that CDN , and now this eror is Uncaught Error: mdc-drawer--persistent class required in root element.